# Change color of an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I want to add a new feature in my HTML page.It is a responsive page. I am using bootstarp css and js .Now I want to change the color of page , that means ,the user select a background color or text color , the page color is changed automatically.
 [Example link](http://shoppica2.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=18)

[image: Like this]

I don't know how to apply this.I need a plugin or something like that. Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3):

To change the colour of an HTML page in JavaScript, you can use the `.backgroundColor` property:

```
document.body.backgroundColor = "#000000";
```

In CSS, you can use the `background-color`:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know , but I need a plugin or something like that

Answer (score 1):

You can use also jquery like :

```
$("body").css("background-color", color);
```

Comment: I know , but I need a plugin or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
function changeBGC(color){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3771236/preview/stock-footage-color-magic-butterfly-on-white-background-with-mask.jpg" alt= "White Background" width="255" height="38" type='button' value='White Background' onclick="changeBGC('#ffffff');return false" />

<img src="http://cdn3.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Plain-Black-Wallpaper.png" alt= "Black Background" width="255" height="38" type="button" value='Black Background' onclick="changeBGC('#000000');return false" />
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a7guj/5/)

Comment: I know , but I need a plugin or something like that

Comment: you can use sticky sidebar instead.